# JQuery validation not getting set

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using javascript to build the html control and them adding them to a table body. I am setting the class to form-control validate so in the save function will set them to required but it is not flagging them you can go right into the save function.

Is there something else I need to add for this validation to work?

Building the form

```
leftSideHtml += "<tr><td style='width:20%><label class='control-label'><span class='required'>*</span>Name</label></td><td><input class='form-control validate' type='text' id='txtName' name='txtName'></input>";

    $("#tblAssetInfoLeftSide tbody").html(leftSideHtml)
```

save function

```
if ($("#form1").validate()) {}
```

validate function

```
$("form1").validate({
    rules: {
        txtName: { required: true }
    },
    messages: {
        txtName: {
            required: "Please enter Asset Name",
        },

    }
});
```

Comment: Where is the rest of this?  Have you included the validation script files after jQuery?  Where are the `form` tags?  Where is the `.validate()` method?  You cannot call `.valid()` without first initializing the plugin.  Where is the `submit` button?  Show us enough code to reconstruct the problem you want to solve.

Comment: I suggest that you read the [Tag Wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) and the [Official Documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) in order to answer your own question.

Comment: Where is the rest?  Why do you have a conditional function at all?  Why did you change `.valid()` into `.validate()`?

Comment: The `input` element is not a container... therefore `<input></input>` is not valid HTML.  It's just a "self-closing" element like this:  `<input />`

Comment: `$("form1")` is not a valid jQuery selector.  If it's an `id`, then it's `$("#form1")`.

Comment: Working for me:  https://jsfiddle.net/84Labesk/

Comment: So can I not use input?

Comment: Did you read anything about I wrote?  `input` element is "self-closing", therefore you do not put a closing tag, so this is NOT valid HTML:  `<input></input>`... only remove the `</input>` tag.  Or just look at the HTML in the jsFiddle I posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have HTML code something like this.

**HTML Code:**

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="target_file_path" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="txtName">Name
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

**Jquery Code:** Here add  valid  jquery selector like : $("#form1")

```
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        txtName: { required: true }
    },
    messages: {
        txtName: {
            required: "Please enter Asset Name",
        },

    }
});
```

Read more information https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ about jquery validation